# Find positive entries in a matrix and show locations

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to write a Mat lab function that finds all positive entries in a matrix and their locations.

This is my code:

```
function [posentry,location]= findpositive(A)
posentry=A(A>0);
[row,col]=find(A>0);
```

I'm not sure how to convert the `row` and `col` obtained with `find` into a single variable `location`. Please explain how to do this.

Comment: What exactly do you call `location`? Do you want the indexes, the linear indexes, a matrix with 1's where A is positive ad 0's elsewhere? What would be the expected output?

Comment: so the output should be the posentry which are those positive number, and the location(row and col) of those positive numbers in the matrix

Comment: Isn't it exactly what you have with your code? I mean, if the question is just about how to concatenate two column vector into a matrix with two column you can just do `location=[row col];`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html?refresh=true#buf0c2r-8) to directly get the [linear indices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html?refresh=true#buf0c2r-8) (i.e. `location`).

```
function [posentry, location] = findpositive(A)
    location = find(A>0);
    posentry=A(location);
end
```

Comment: thanks but it didn't show the location of the positive values. Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean? Because if I generate some random numbers, i.e. `A = rand(10,1)-0.5`, and feed that to the function, it does give me the correct indices... also, when you call the function, are you requesting two return values?